# Delete rows where a level of multindex is nan (Pandas)

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following table with a multindex

```
                       value
userid     date

NaN        2014-06-12   42799
           2014-06-13   47673
           2014-06-14   47042
           2014-06-15   48079
           2014-06-16   44873
           2014-06-17   46586
           2014-06-18   44575
1000000021 2014-06-17   0
1000000024 2014-06-22   20
1000000043 2014-06-12   14
           2014-06-14   22
          .
          .
          .
          .
```

I would like to drop the row where the userid is Nan. If I wanted to drop another row I could do

```
data = data.drop(1000000021)
```

but

```
data = data.drop('NaN')
data = data.drop(np.nan)
```

and other attempts all return errors of differing varieties. Is there a way to drop the row without having to reindex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could identify the rows whose index is NaN using `df.index.labels[0] == -1`, and select the other rows using `df.loc`:

```
In [48]: df.loc[~(df.index.labels[0] == -1)]
Out[48]: 
                       value
userid     date             
1000000021 2014-06-17      0
1000000024 2014-06-22     20
1000000043 2014-06-12     14
           2014-06-14     22
```

When using a boolean index, `df[...]`, `df.loc[...]`, and `df.iloc[...]` all behave the same. `df[...]` is commonly used to select columns, however, so you might want to avoid using `df[...]` for also selecting rows, as done above. That leaves `df.loc` and `df.iloc` as viable choices. Since `df.iloc` was created mainly for selecting by integer index, you might want to use `df.loc[...]` for selecting by label *and* by boolean mask. But this is just my convention -- Pandas allows all three.

Comment: I already tried something like this. isnull is not defined for MultiIndex so the command would be more like df.loc[~pd.isnull(data.index.levels[0])] but this does not work since the returned array ignores the NaN value.

Comment: Oh, I misread your DataFrame. Try `df.loc[~(df.index.labels[0] == -1)]`.

Comment: This runs. If you are planning on suggesting df=df.loc[~(df.index.labels[0] == np.nan)] it does not work for the same reason as above. The df.index.labels[0] array does not contain the NaN value so I can't select on it.

Comment: @user262536 the labels array of a MultiIndex is a location of the levels, so -1 is a missing value

Answer (score 0):

Easier to reset and drop from the frame, then set the index.

```
In [3]: df =  DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,10,size=16).reshape(-1,1),columns=['value'],index=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([[np.nan,1,2,3],pd.date_range('20130101',periods=4)],names=['first','second']))

In [4]: df
Out[4]: 
                  value
first second           
NaN   2013-01-01      0
      2013-01-02      2
      2013-01-03      9
      2013-01-04      3
1     2013-01-01      8
      2013-01-02      8
      2013-01-03      5
      2013-01-04      3
2     2013-01-01      4
      2013-01-02      1
      2013-01-03      2
      2013-01-04      7
3     2013-01-01      3
      2013-01-02      9
      2013-01-03      3
      2013-01-04      4

In [5]: df.reset_index().dropna(subset=['first']).set_index(['first','second'])
Out[5]: 
                  value
first second           
1     2013-01-01      8
      2013-01-02      8
      2013-01-03      5
      2013-01-04      3
2     2013-01-01      4
      2013-01-02      1
      2013-01-03      2
      2013-01-04      7
3     2013-01-01      3
      2013-01-02      9
      2013-01-03      3
      2013-01-04      4
```